# c++ valgrind double pointer delete for memory leak prevention

Tags: c++, valgrind, double-pointer

After reading:
[C++ Array of pointers: delete or delete []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814188/c-array-of-pointers-delete-or-delete)
(reply by shai vashid)
and
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6651/

I implemented following:

Kernel.h

```
unsigned int **ConfigMeM;
//.....
~Kernel(){ //destructor
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<MeMSize; i++)
        delete [] MeM[i]; //Valgrind:- Invalid read of size 4
                                       - Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
    delete [] MeM; //Valgrind: Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<_item_tot; i++)
        delete [] ConfigMeM[i]; //Valgrind: Same comments as above
    delete [] ConfigMeM; //Valgrind: same as above
};
```

Kernel.cpp

```
//.......
MeM = new unsigned int*[MeMSize];
for (unsigned int i=0; i<MeMSize; i++){
    MeM[i] = new unsigned int[11]; //Valgrind: 14,608 bytes in 332 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,021 of 2,036
}
for (unsigned int i=0; i<MeMSize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
        MeM[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
 //.....
 ConfigMeM = new unsigned int*[_item_tot];
for (unsigned int i=0; i<_item_tot; i++){
    ConfigMeM[i] = new unsigned int[3]; //Valgrind: 1,200 bytes in 100 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,131 of 2,036 
}
for (unsigned int i=0; i<_item_tot; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
        ConfigMeM[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
  //.....
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running the code in Kernel.cpp multiple times?

Comment: Is the code from Kernel.cpp part of the constructor, or something else? Are you declaring your own copy constructor and copy-assignment operator (per the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722))? My guess is that you aren't, and you're ending up with two objects trying to delete the same memory.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, you are right! In a top module several copies of Kernel are created. For example in the current example it is 64. How does that matter here?!

Comment: "How does it matter?" Think about this: `int * p = new int; p = new int; p = new int; delete p;`

Comment: @KerrekSB I did not mean to challenge you!! I just want to ask now what can I do to and how shall I modify my code?

Comment: I wasn't feeling challenged :-) I just gave you a simple example that demonstrates the problem, as well as suggests the solution: delete the existing object before allocating a new one!

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that an object your class is being copied using the implicitly-generated copy constructor or copy-assignment operator. This would leave two objects with pointers to the same memory; both would try to delete this memory on destruction, resulting in double-delete errors.

The easiest fix is to prevent copying by deleting these functions:

```
Kernel(Kernel const&) = delete;
void operator=(Kernel const &) = delete;
```

or, if you're stuck with an ancient compiler, declare them private with no function body.

If you need to copy these objects, then you will need to implement these, perhaps to perform a "deep copy" that allocates new blocks of memory.

Alternatively, it might be easier to use `std::vector` to manage your dynamic arrays; this already has correct copy semantics, and can be initialised quite simply:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> MeM, ConfigMem;

(MemSize, std::vector<unsigned int>(11));
```